# htaccess file ignored addhandler and directoryindex sttings not executed

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have just set up Apache server with php and mysql server. 
My problem is that my html files have php blocks in them , but they are not executed at all.
If the html file is included in a php file, the blocks are executed. So it seems that the html files are not served by the php module.

I tried to change this in the htaccess file:

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /

#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .php 
#AddHandler php5-script  .php
#AddHandler php5-script  .html

#AddType text/html .php
#AddType text/html .html
#AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

RemoveHandler .html .htm AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm

DirectoryIndex home.html index.php
```

I can tell that the htaccess file is ignored because it does not carry out the directoryIndex command.
I have tried all the above AddType and AddHandler that are now commented out.

I have added to the httpd.conf file:

```
AllowOverride All
```

But when I save it an alert comes up stating that file is uploaded successfully but error ocured when setting permissions or timestamp.

In Apache docs It advises me to turn on ignore permission errors in a certain dialog box, but I don't see these dialog boxes anywhere. 
Where can I look for these. Is it in WinSCP? if so where.

Am I looking in the right direction for my html with php blocks problem , 
or is addingHandler and addType not going to solve the problem.
What is the best place to put these changes?

Comment: Did you add `AllowOverride All` to the Directory directive of your conf?

Comment: I don't really understand why you want html templates to be run handled by php interpreter. Why don't you just put html code to your php files and not vica versa? (Eg rename html files to php)

Comment: I put the AllowOverride in the httpd.conf file. I actually believe that somehow the server ignores this file as well as I put the DirectoryIndex home.html command there as well(I put it there as a check, to see if the changes have any effect, and they don't. )Is there supposed to be a VHOST file that takes precedence over everything? (I'm on Amazon)And where or how can I find it .Can I find it with a command using Putty?

Comment: I use the php blocks in the html files to include content like the navigation bar, headers and also custom objects that look the same on each page but read a different content from a file before it is included on the page. If I make it into a php file, I need to echo all the html  parts, and then you get a problem with alternating double quotes and single quotes. Also I already have my whole site set up this way. It would be a big job to change it. My site was first on another host, and there it was no problem at all. So I just need to get these .html files served

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble. It turned out that just changing the file extension  from html to php was enough. 
I always thought that you had to echo any HTML content on a php page , but that is not true.
So now it just runs.
Thanks